# How can I hide the start of an element instead of the end when it get's overlapped?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am trying to get a div element to hide the beginning of it's text opposed to the end. If this does not make sense, please see the fiddle -
 http://jsfiddle.net/L7zd8uyb/1/

As you reduce the width of the screen, 'paragraph' will hide behind the right-most div. Is it possible to reach this div and then start to hide 'some' behind the left-most div?

HTML:

```
<div id="leftside">Left</div>
<div id="rightside">Right</div>

<div>
    <span>Some paragraph.</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#leftside {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#rightside{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
span {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

Note: The JSFiddle was simplified from the example provided in this question - [How can I prevent HTML elements from overlapping or sliding under one another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553273/how-can-i-prevent-html-elements-from-overlapping-or-sliding-under-one-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `margin-left: 200px` is preventing it from being overlapped by your `#leftside` div.

Try this for your CSS:

```
#leftside {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2; /* this will overlap #rightside */
}


#rightside{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 1; /* this will overlap span */
}
span {
  position: fixed;
  left: 40%; /* change this to what you need, depending on #leftside */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these styles:

```
span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 150px;                  /* width of Right element */
  white-space: nowrap;           /* prevent wrapping */
  min-width: calc(100% - 350px); /* difference of Left and Right widths */
}

#leftside {
  z-index: 1;                   /* cover the middle element if needed */
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ahhq31bc/)